# How to avoid the "Duplicate status message" error in using Facebook SDK in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, duplicates

I want to post the several same messages onto my feed/wall in an iOS application.

From the 2nd try, I receive this error -

> (#506) Duplicate status message.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You can't.**

That is Facebook's way to tell you to stop spamming.

Sorry if it sounds slightly mean - but posting the same message over and over and over again is spamming, and its not good.  The error message you are getting describes the problem - you are posting the same status message.  It is a special error message created specifically for this case.

Comment: However, some application is applied it. How did they code it?

Comment: If some application is managing to do that they are bypassing Facebook's security features and they should be reported.  By doing this you are likely to be "punished" by Facebook.  They might disable your application/page/user...etc... **I do not recommend it**

Comment: I don't mean the spamming. User will confirm the posting message everytime. And user can change the message, too. Once the user inputs the same message, then ...

Comment: Even if you do this manually directly on Facebook you will not be allowed to post the same message twice... [You'll see this error](http://i.imgur.com/yDkap.png).  If the status update is **different** it will not be a problem.

Comment: I heard that after re-login on facebook, you can post the same message again. How can I relogin without any user interface?

Comment: You are now asking a different question from your original one.  Perhaps you should search [so] for an answer to the `login/relogn` problem.  For now I think we have gone as far as we can.

Comment: I mean no offence but I strongly disagree with what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Lix I found this post while searching for a solution to my problem. I created an app from which you can share photos. Together with the photo I post also a message saying: "Made with: NAME_OF_MY_APP". I don't see why this should be considered spam :)

Comment: @and - This message should only be seen if you are actually posting the same content twice. Are you also getting the "duplicate message" error?

Answer (score 1):

I check for the 506 code and don't show any error to the user in case it's a duplicate status error

```
if (error && [[[[[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] objectForKey:@"body"]objectForKey:@"error"]objectForKey:@"code"] intValue] !=506) {

 alertTitle = NSLocalizedString( @"SomethingWentWrongTitle", nil);

}
```