# How to avoid the "Feed action request limit reached" error using Facebook SDK in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

> Disclaimer - It's not **spam**. In the application, the user will be confirm the message everytime.
>    I just want a app like a "Status Shuffle". Tesing this app, I found that using this app, I can post the multiple same messages and unlimited messages onto facebook without any error.

I want to post the unlimited numbers of messages onto Facebook, but I can not find the way.

How can I implement it?

On the other hand - as I heard, you can post again after re-log into Facebook.

How can I re-log into Facebook in iOS internally? That is, without any user interface.

Comment: Unlimited messages onto facebook, e.g.... spamming?

Comment: Seriously?  Are you **trying** to spam users?

Comment: @Lix: yes, the keyword is 'trying' - thankfully, and obviously, not successful... yet.

Comment: *It's not **spam**. In the application, the user will be confirm the message everytime. User may want it.

Comment: Exceptions to guidelines are seldom granted on the basis of a pledge. The guidelines are there because pledges aren't worth the words that form them.

Comment: Sorry for my bad expression ability. I just want a app like a "Status Shuffle". Tesing this app, I found that using this app, I can post the multiple same messages and unlimited messages onto facebook without any error. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, be careful not to abuse the Facebook API functionality as you may find yourself cut off from the service if you engage in `spammy` behaviour.

In terms of relogging in without the use of a user interface, you can simply re-establish a new access token to continue using your application functionality.

**Reference**: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/reauthentication/

Comment: I believe re-authentication is different from logging out and then back in... I think it just asks for your password again but doesn't necessarily log you out...

Comment: Sorry for my bad expression ability. I just want a app like a "Status Shuffle". Tesing this app, I found that using this app, I can post the multiple same messages and unlimited messages onto facebook without any error. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting here can not be by-passed by simply logging out and back in again.  [I've heard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384152/how-to-avoid-the-duplicate-status-message-error-in-using-facebook-sdk-in-ios/11384187#11384187) that that will work for the "duplicate status message" error but what you are seeing here is **a limit that Facebook has set for your application**.  It doesn't matter how many times the user logs out and back in - **they are still using your application and will still be affected by the limitations that are enforced.**

---

### Be warned!

If Facebook were to "catch" you bypassing their security features, **they will take action** against you/your application/your user/your page...etc...

I speak out of personal experience here...

Comment: Sorry for my bad expression ability. I just want a app like a "Status Shuffle". Tesing this app, I found that using this app, I can post the multiple same messages and unlimited messages onto facebook without any error. How can I implement it?