# "Duplicate status message" error from Facebook graph API

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, compiler-errors

I get the following message in the facebook graph API:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#506) Duplicate status message",
    "type":"OAuthException",
    "code":506,
    "error_data": {
      "kError":1455006
    }
  }
}
```

Can anybody explains what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(#506) Duplicate status message` means that you have posted a message in a small period of time from a previous one

More here

> [How to avoid the "Duplicate status message" error in using Facebook SDK in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384152/how-to-avoid-the-duplicate-status-message-error-in-using-facebook-sdk-in-ios)